# Drawline in parallel for loop

Tags: c#, drawing, parallel.for

I would like to speed up the drawing of lines. Why does the parallel for loop not work? It does not draw anything.

I'm also open to other ideas how to speed it up.

*I edited the code for incremental for loop. Though I get "A first chance exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in SharpDX.Direct2D1.dll" during the drawing? livePoints is a simple list.*

Some code:

```
private RenderTarget m_d2dRenderTarget;
...
m_d2dRenderTarget.BeginDraw();
//Drawing lines using the loop
m_d2dRenderTarget.EndDraw();
```

Standard for loop:

```
for (int i = livePoints.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            m_d2dRenderTarget.DrawLine(livePoints[i - 1],
                                    livePoints[i], solidColorBrush, (float)1.5);
        }
```

Parallel for loop:

```
Parallel.For(1, livePoints.Count-1, i =>
        {
            m_d2dRenderTarget.DrawLine(livePoints[i - 1],
                                    livePoints[i], solidColorBrush, (float)1.5);
        });
```

Comment: Just curious, why in your `standard for loop` you have `> 0 + 1` ??

Comment: standard loop is decremental, Parralel works incremental. Switch your first 2 parameters into your Parralel.For statement

Comment: Sorry gleng, copy/paste mistake. Edited it. Are you familiar with for loops? Is it that I can not access the running variable like that or that the target is living in different tasks?

Comment: I changed the code accordingly to your comments but still it does not run. See my note within the post. I guess it is SharpDX specific. Ideas?

Comment: I know now that Direct2D1.DrawXXX is not threadsafe. Any Chance to Speed Drawline up?